# How to check my website access through webproxy server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check my website access through web proxy server in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

```
    string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    string APIKey = "<Your API Key>";
    string url = string.Format("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key={0}&ip={1}&format=json", APIKey, ipAddress);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
        Location location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Location>(json);
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
        locations.Add(location);
        gvLocation.DataSource = locations;
        gvLocation.DataBind();
    }
```

//Add class

```
    string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    string APIKey = "<Your API Key>";
    string url = string.Format("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key={0}&ip={1}&format=json", APIKey, ipAddress);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
        Location location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Location>(json);
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
        locations.Add(location);
        gvLocation.DataSource = locations;
        gvLocation.DataBind();
    }


public string IPAddress { get; set; }
public string CountryName { get; set; }
public string CountryCode { get; set; }
public string CityName { get; set; }
public string RegionName { get; set; }
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
public string Latitude { get; set; }
public string Longitude { get; set; }
public string TimeZone { get; set; }
```